# APDU throwing 6F00 on a method

Tags: smartcard, javacard, apdu

I am trying to read data from an incoming smart card APDU and return the same incoming message while also appending the ASCII words "respond " to the front of the message. I am getting a `6F00` status. How should I fix the codes?

My codes:

```
private void repeat(APDU apdu) {
    byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
    apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
    byte[] incomingMsg = getData(buffer);
    if ((short) incomingMsg.length != (short) 0) {
        apdu.setOutgoing();

        // Send back the "respond " + "<incoming message" back
        byte[] respMsg = {0x72, 0x65, 0x73, 0x70, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x64, 0x20};
        byte[] outgoingMsg = new byte[(short) (incomingMsg.length + respMsg.length)];
        ArrayLogic.arrayCopyRepack(respMsg, (short) 0, (short) respMsg.length, outgoingMsg, (short) 0);
        ArrayLogic.arrayCopyRepack(incomingMsg, (short) 0, (short) incomingMsg.length, outgoingMsg, (short) respMsg.length);
        buffer = outgoingMsg;
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) outgoingMsg.length);
    }
}

private byte[] getData(byte[] buffer) {
    short msgLen = (short) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] & 0x00FF);
    short readPos = 5;
    short msgPos = 0;
    byte[] msg = new byte[msgLen];
    while (msgPos < msgLen) {
        msg[msgPos] = buffer[readPos];
        readPos++;
        msgPos++;
    }
    return msg;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically, the status word `6F00` means that your code throws an unhandled exception. In your case, this could be caused by the use of both `apdu.setOutgoing()` and `apdu.setOutgoingAndSend()`. You may switch to outbound data direction only once. Hence, the use of `apdu.setOutgoing()` and `apdu.setOutgoingAndSend()` is mutually exclusive. In fact, you may use only one of the `apdu.setOutgoing*()` methods.

If you want to use `apdu.setOutgoing()`, you would later send data using `apdu.sendBytes()` or `apdu.sendBytesLong()`.

#### Other problems in your code

There is a couple of other severe coding issues in your program.

1. Note that Java Card smartcards won't perform automatic garbage collection. Hence, allocating new byte arrays (and dropping the references to them) upon every invocation of your processing code will typically result into a memory leak (i.e. you use up all the memory of your card as the byte arrays remain allocated even if you no longer reference them).
2. The code

   ```
   buffer = outgoingMsg;
   apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) outgoingMsg.length);
   ```

   will not do what you might expect. `setOutgoingAndSend()` (just as (`sendBytes()`) will send bytes from the global APDU buffer (i.e. from byte array referenced through `apdu.getBuffer()`. Simply setting your local `buffer` variable to reference to another byte array (`outgoingMsg`) will not change the global APDU buffer. Instead you would need to copy your outgoing data into the APDU buffer (see `Util.arrayCopy*()`). Alternatively, you could use `apdu.sendBytesLong()` to specify a byte array containing the data to send.

Comment: Dear Micheal, I modified the questioner's program and there is a weird problem. When I remove the line `ArrayLogic.arrayCopyRepack(incomingMsg, (short) 0, (short) incomingMsg.length, outgoingMsg, (short) respMsg.length);` then I can install the `.cap` file, but when I add it to my program, I can't install the applet anymore! I receive `0x6A80` error in the installation step for this line. Have you any idea what is the origin of this error?

Comment: @Abraham: I have no problem installing my original code. I used the gp.jar from "https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro". Which GP tool are you using ? I ran the gp.jar tool in debug and verbose mode and I saw all 9000 with CAP loaded status.

Comment: @Michael Roland: Do I have to simply apdu.sendLongBytes(outgoingMsg, (short) 0, (short) outgoingMsg.length) or must I also setOutgoing. Currently I am only using sendLongBytes with no setOutgoing* am still getting the exact same status error. I am trying to figure out what kind of exception it can throw. What exception should I throw and how do I catch it ? By the way I am using a real dev card.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's solved. Need to set outGoingLength before doing sendBytesLong which I missed.

Comment: @Abraham `ArrayLogic` is an optional class. If your card does not implement it, the on-card installer component will reject your applet.